# How can I access Entity Type information in EF Core with code first?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

In Entity Framework Core, how can I access the Entity Type data (the entity names, regular properties, navigation properties, etc.) when using code-first? When using database-first, I can use [Scaffolding or Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) and from EF Core 7 onward, I can even use [Custom Reverse Engineering Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates). I'd like to be able to access the same Entity Type information when using code-first whether that be in T4 or in plain C#. Based on the default T4 template in EF Core 7, the information I am after is in the `Model` parameter (of type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel`) that gets set as a parameter:

```
<#@ parameter name="Model" type="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel" #>
```

I'm essentially asking a variation of this [EF 6 question about DbContext Generation T4 Templates With Code-First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) but for EF Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it on an instance of `DbContext`. There is property `Model` available.

**Related information**

[DbContext.Model Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.model?view=efcore-8.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-model)

Comment: @JohnCummings, DbSet property is syntax sugar, EF do not use in runtime these properties for functioning. Referencing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` is tricky, check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77293158/10646316)

Comment: Simple enough - thank you. Now I'm fighting getting access to the extensions methods such as GetDbSetName provided by [ScaffoldingModelExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.scaffoldingmodelextensions) Visual Studio and the compiler can't seem to find them even with a using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design and those packages installed.